# Different for-"definitions/conditions but same execution code

Tags: python

Just out of curiosity, is something like this possible in Python?

Instead of

```
if opt1:
    for x in array1:
        *a lot of lines of code doing something with x*
elif opt2:
    for x in array2:
        *exactly the same code doing something with x*
```

doing something like

```
if opt1:
    for x in array1: #returning a "for-handle" for the for-loop
elif opt2:
    for x in array2: #returning a modified "for-handle"
        *a lot of code doing something with x* #executing code
```

I.e. redefining the "for-condition" depending on some option, but still keep the same "execution code" inside the for-loop?

I have a big block of code inside the for-loop, but instead of duplicating it for a couple of different options I was thinking if the above mentioned pseudocode was possible.

P.S. Yes I know that there are perhaps neater workarounds and other solutions to this problem, but I'm curious!

Comment: Sounds like the inside of the loop should be extracted the a function. You could also just create a variable `array` that you set to either `array1` or `array2` in the if-block, and do `for x in array` after the if-block.

Comment: Just a note:  In general, the imaginary "`for`-handle" you're looking for is called a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. What I did was to move it to a function. I think the beauty with Python is that once you think "Oh this must me possible! I wonder how though..." it usually is possible in some way. So I thought there might be a trick to do this. But apparently not in the way of my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if opt1:
    my_array = array1
elif opt2:
    my_array = array2
else:
    my_array = []

for x in my_array:
    ...
```

or, somewhat cleverer:

```
for x in array1 if opt1 else array2 if opt2 else []:
    ...
```

Comment: For a second I misread it as "somewhat clearer", and I was going to object to that description.

Comment: I like your one-liner! I will use that the next time I run into this problem. Thank you.